# Regex match number in string C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get the total price from a receipt with Regex.

The formatting is:

```
TOTAL     15.40
```

The goal is only to get the price out of the string.

I started with `TOTAL[ .0-9]`, but this only returned the word `TOTAL`.

I googled around and putted this one together but can't get it to work:

```
TOTAL(\\s+)(?<value>[.0-9]+)
```

I have made the following code:

```
sRegex = "TOTAL(\\s+)(?<value>[.0-9]+)";    
Match match = Regex.Match(this.sHTMLResult, sRegex, RegexOptions.None);
if (match.Success)
    Console.Out.WriteLine("regex good");
else
    Console.Out.WriteLine("regex fail");
```

But the regex doesn't return a success.

I try to get it out of a HTML file formatted like this:

```
TOTAL&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;15.40
```

Comment: Works for me. I get a match with the capture group containing `15.40`. Check your inputs.

Comment: Good point, I tested with only the text and it works, but I try to get it out of a HTML file formatted like this: TOTAL&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;15.40 Probably the regex doesn't see &nbsp; as space

Comment: http://txt2re.com/ should be your new friend.  The outputted regex isn't perfect, but it gives you a good starting point.

Comment: There you go. Don't use regex to parse HTML, or at least convert HTML to regular text before hand.

Comment: @GerardvandenBosch - `&nbsp;` is not a space, obviously.

Comment: Ok I will convert it to text first, thank you for the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial regular expression works fine with the supplied text:

```
TOTAL(\\s+)(?<value>[.0-9]+)
```

However, as you indicated in comments, this is from HTML and contains the character entities for no break spaces, so you need to account for those as well:

```
TOTAL(\\s+|(&nbsp;)+)(?<value>[.0-9]+)
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, I took your suggestion from the comments already and converted it to plain text first before doing the regex and that works great.

Answer (score 1):

You might use:

`"TOTAL *(\d*.\d*)"`

Comment: In .NET `\d` will match on all numerals, not only `[0-9]` (so, Arabic numerals will match, for example).

Answer (score 1):

`(?(\b.*\b\s)([0-9.]*[0-9]))` should work.

I would recommend you to use the [Regex hero online editor](http://regexhero.net/tester/) which is at least really helpful for me.

Comment: Why is this better than the regex from the OP?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex works (check your input as suggested), but it has a small bug: it would capture any combination of digits and dots (like 333.3.2.22....) A better one would be:

```
TOTAL\s+(?<value>\d+\.\d+)
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have only a single whitespace between TOTAL and the amount you can use a whitespace in the regex. Additionally, try this:

```
sRegex = "TOTAL ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)";
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx) for the MSDN reference.

Comment: You will note that the regex posted by the OP is fine. If that isn't matching, why would your match any better?